# MSAL js:- How to ask user for login details every time if the session is not available

Tags: javascript, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am using msal.js in my application. I have a couple of Identity Providers like Yahoo, Google, AAD, etc. so that user can signin with any one of these accounts. but the problem is whenever I call loginpopup() method in msal service, It is taking automatially the logged in mail account.

Any solution for this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, get rid of MSAL.